# Why is it impossible to save objects in two dimesional array?

Tags: javascript

I want to have a two dimensional variable in javascript, in one dimension I want to save objects and in the second dimension save the string.

Consider the code below:

```
var certificate = [Certificate Object , "Certificate Issuer name as string"];
```

but the code above is not working! Is there any consideration?

Comment: You should use an object, not an array, anyway, it's not two dimensional array.

Comment: What isn't working? What is the output of `console.log(certificate);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is an object in javascript.
What you want to achieve is very much possible however in a different manner.

you can create an object (as @gdoron) pointed out. You can try having the string as key and the object as value.

```
var certificate = {
           "Certificate Isser name as string":Certificate Object
};
```

I hope this solves the purpose

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want a hashmap instead of a 2D array.
In this case and if the "Certificate Isser name as string" is unique for each Certificate Object, your code is going to be very simple:

```
var certificate = {};    
certificate["Certificate Isser name as string"] = Certificate Object;
```

Otherwise a 2D array is done like this:

```
var certificate = [];
certificate.push([Certificate Object , "Certificate Isser name as string"]);
console.log(certificate[0][1]); // prints: "Certificate Isser name as string"
```